# Something in Webrtcbin is holding up packets up to 1 second

Tags: gstreamer

I was looking at some stats from the internal webrtcbin queues of an application and noticed that some of the internal queues fill up, and during specific scenarios.

The internal queue names are enumerated; i.e. `queue1`, `queue2`, etc.

When a single audio and video stream (i.e. one device) is connected, the queues never fill or even breach 20 ms.

However when there are two streams (i.e. two webrtcbins), then I start to see one of the webrtcbin queues show very high queue times.

The queue in question is right before `GstRtpBin`. Has anyone experienced this?

`audio/video compositing -> GstRtpFunnel -> GstQueue (blows up) -> GstRtpBin`

The above elements are all internal to webrtcbin.

The same queue that's fine when only one device is connected blows up when another one joins. There are two `compositors` and two `audiomixers` in the pipeline as well, however these are prior to the queue (but may also play a role).

The `latency` value on the jitter buffer is 50.

Some more information:

These the elements present in the pipeline prior to Webrtcbin:

```
audioconvert
audiomixer
audiotestsrc
fakesink
identity
queue (other queues are not full)
tee
videoconvert
videoscale
videotestsrc
```

I have an inclination that the problem has to do with the audio stream causing an overall delay at the end sink.

Comment: Can you post your complete pipelines?

Comment: Unfortunately no as it is a confidential app - I wish I could. I can certain answer any questions though. Is it possible the aggregators are setting the PTS higher (or some other element prior is waiting)?

Comment: Im starting to think the reason is related to the audio/video rates. Is that something I should be concerned with?